# mouseover работает не так, как нужно

Tags: javascript, html, css, mouse-event

Всем привет, есть одна проблема насчёт mouseover. При наведении на определённый элемент он должен появлятся, но почему-то если наводишься на сам список то всё равно элемент отображается. Пробовал собственно ручно решить этот косяк, но не получилось. Надеюсь, что вы сможете помочь разобраться мне в этом. Прикрепляю код

```js
const links = document.getElementById('links');
var telegram = document.querySelector('.fa-telegram');
links.addEventListener('mouseenter', function(event) {
  if (event.target === telegram) {
    telegram.classList.add('fadeIn');
    telegram.classList.remove('fadeOut');
  }
});
links.addEventListener('mouseleave', function(event) {
  if (event.target === telegram) {
    telegram.classList.add('fadeOut');
    telegram.classList.remove('fadeIn');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <ul id="links">
    <li><i class="fa-brands fa-telegram" style="color: #ffffff;"></i></li>
    <li><a href="">TG</a></li>
    <li><a href="">VK</a></li>
    <li><a href="">DS</a></li>
    <li><a href="">GIT</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Во-первых, не mouseover, а mouseenter. Во-вторых, условие `event.target === telegram` всегда будет ложным. В-третьих, а что вам помешало реализовать то, что вы пытаетесь сделать, на чистом CSS без всяких скриптов?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Немного странный код - подобное проще было бы решить обычными стилями без js. mouseenter/mouseleave в коде - это однозначно противоречит проверке конкретного дочернего элемента ниже (не всплывает и никогда не будет event.target === telegram ), во-вторых, добавление и удаление сразу класса - если идея была сделать hover - то не сработало бы - слишком быстро отработало бы. Как минимум нужно было добавить setTimeout на 2е добавление/удаление класса. А так рабочий вариант ниже.

```js
const links = document.getElementById('links');
var telegram = document.querySelector('.fa-telegram');

links.addEventListener('mouseover', function(event) {
  if (event.target === telegram) {
    telegram.classList.add('fadeIn');
    // telegram.classList.remove('fadeOut');
  }
});
links.addEventListener('mouseout', function(event) {
  if (event.target === telegram) {
    // telegram.classList.add('fadeOut');
    telegram.classList.remove('fadeIn');
  }
});
```

```css
.fa-telegram {
  transition: opacity 1s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.fadeIn {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.fadeOut {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <ul id="links">
    <li><i class="fa-brands fa-telegram" style="color: #f00;">hover</i></li>
    <li><a href="">TG</a></li>
    <li><a href="">VK</a></li>
    <li><a href="">DS</a></li>
    <li><a href="">GIT</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Если делать через :hover, то иконка будет отображаться если в точности на неё навестить. Я хотел реализовать если навестить на текст, то будет отображаться иконка. Через hover тупо невозможно сделать, потому-что нужный мне pointer-events: none; мешает его работе.

Comment: совсем не понятна общая идея, пока я вижу иконку телеграма саму по себе и ниже тексты. Либо вы что-то не допечатали и иконок должно быть больше у каждого текста, либо задумка сложнее чем кажется. Скорректируйте код этих ссылок на более близкий к задумке.

Comment: @bebralitydev что-то ничего не понятно, в вашем скрипте вы тоже никак не взаимодействуете с текстом